# In Java, how do I create a Class like the KeyListener where if you extend it, it automatically calls methods?

Tags: java, abstraction

I am working on a Library in Java and I am starting to optimize it and make it very easy for the user to use. Can I make a class similar to `KeyListener` where when you extend it then it will call implemented methods? For example the user would extend my `Game` class and they would implement things like the `tick` method which would be automatically updated from the Superclass.

Comment: I can't fully understand your problem.

Comment: Yes, they are called interfaces and you could use an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to implement the functionality.  Now, these methods to "magically" get called, you actually need to something to call them, this means that something must implement the interface, something would be required to accept the interface (register against) which would then, based on the contract of the interface, call the required methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be achieved by implementing Observer pattern. The class implemented as Observable will notify the Observer class.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible (as long as you have a background thread to call `tick()`). In `KeyListener`'s case there's also native code down the line, but you don't need that to create this kind of functionality.